# Select and list all the adjacent features of a feature in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-location, select-by-expression

I have a shapefile of the Zips of California like the attached image. What I want is to select the adjacent/neighboring polygons (those touch the boundary) of each polygon in ArcMap and want to create a list of the Adjacent polygons for each polygons to use in Excel. I know there is select by location option that can be used to select the polygons that touches a polygon. But since I have almost 1700+ zip code polygons how can I do that easily without doing it one by one. For Example

[image]

in this image I want to list all the neighboring zips polygon for "93208" (The big pink Polygon in the rectangle box)  may be in another field like (93285, 93250, ...........) and then export to Excel. The main point here is to know how can do it at once for all the zips.

Is that possible in ArcMap?

Comment: Use the BOUNDARY_TOUCHES option in Select by Location. But not all zipcodes are one polygon it is known to be an erroneous dataset.

Comment: Thanks. I know the Boundary touches Option. But what if i want to know the touching polygon info for not only one feature but many of them at once?

And yes zipcodes cant be polygon areas. This image is  just uses as a sample  of the many polygons

Comment: Have you looked at the Polygon Neighbors tool?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Polygon Neighbors tool. Then perform a table join using nbr_FID from PolygonNeighbors result table and your original Features FID.